# When I try to expose Vue type according official website, I still get error

Tags: typescript, vue.js

```js
// shims-vue.d.ts
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    // ...
    // 以下是在main.ts中挂载到Vue.prototype上的变量
    $someFn: () => void;
  }
}
```

```js
// About.vue
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

export default class About extends Vue {
  public created(): void {
    this.$someFn();
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
12:10 Property '$someFn' does not exist on type 'About'.
    10 | export default class About extends Vue {
    11 |   public created(): void {
  > 12 |     this.$someFn();
       |          ^
    13 |   }
    14 | }
    15 | </script>
```

https://cn.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#%E5%A2%9E%E5%BC%BA%E7%B1%BB%E5%9E%8B%E4%BB%A5%E9%85%8D%E5%90%88%E6%8F%92%E4%BB%B6%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8